# RTC management in desktop and embedded environments

Tags: debian, cron, date, clock

When working on an embedded environment (current one: Raspberry Pi with Debian Stretch) with an external RTC module (i.e. DS1307) I have to manually keep in sync both system and RTC clock.

This can be achieved periodically calling `hwclock -w` - putting it in a cron job for example.

I'm curious how the desktop systems handle this situation. Inspetting the cron jobs on my Debian desktop machine it seems there is nothing related to the RTC (although it could be "hidden" in some other tasks).

So, how the RTC is kept in sync with the system clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On embedded platforms like the Pi that do not come with a RTC the package `adjtimex` is not normally installed by default. This is the tool that manages the kernels RTC configuration, and defaults to configuring the kernel to keep the hw clock in sync with the system clock.

Note that if you use hwclock or similar it will disable the kernel sync and you will need to use adjtimex to re-enable it again.

`adjtimex` is a solution for machines with intermittant or no connectivity for time sync. The other option is to use `ntpd` which can be configured to keep the system clock correct, and on shutdown a script calls `hwclock --systortc` to write the last most correct clock to the hwclock.